# Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, nuxt.js, onesignal

I'm trying to enable OneSignal notification in my pwa nuxtjs app.

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/onesignal',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
  ],

  oneSignal: {
    cdn: true,
    OneSignalSDK: 'https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js',
    init: {
      appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
      allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true,
      welcomeNotification: {
          disable: true
      }
    }
  },
  workbox: {
    dev: true,
    debug: true
  },
```

I'm getting the popup notification and when I press `Accept`, the following error occures:

> A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
>   sw.js?1557093232129:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute
>
> 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at
>   'http://localhost:3333/_nuxt/workbox.dev.4c4f5ca6.js' failed to load.
>       at http://localhost:3333/sw.js?1557093232129:1:1
>       at http://localhost:3333/OneSignalSDKWorker.js?appId=xxxxxxxx:1:1
>   (anonymous) @ sw.js?1557093232129:1
>
> ServiceWorkerManager.js:371 [Service Worker Installation] Installing
>   service worker failed TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker:
>   ServiceWorker script evaluation failed

I have the `sw.js` file in the static folder as well. Found similar issues in the Github issues section, but no real solutions.

Comment: Have you checked [this github post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996739/failed-to-execute-importscripts-on-workerglobalscope)?

Comment: the link seems dead [*] @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0

Answer (score 6):

Our service workers OneSignalSDKWorker.js and OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js overwrite other service workers that are registered with the topmost (site root) service worker scope. The solution is to merge all other service worker scripts into our service worker scripts using importScripts() and to register the merged service worker instead of the original worker.

Both OneSignalSDKWorker.js and OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js contain the following code:

```
importScripts('https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDKWorker.js');
```

Please modify both OneSignalSDKWorker.js and OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js to import your other service worker scripts, like:

```
importScripts('https://example.com/sw.js');
importScripts('https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDKWorker.js');
```

We recommend the above approach instead of importing our service worker into another file because our web SDK replaces other workers that are registered on the root scope.

Additionally, please be sure to modify your site's code to register OneSignalSDKWorker.js instead of your own worker. You can do this with code like:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/OneSignalSDKWorker.js');
```

Info on [service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers)

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration should be like this :

```
  oneSignal: {
    cdn: true,
    OneSignalSDK: 'https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js',
    init: {
      appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
      allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true,
      welcomeNotification: {
          disable: true
      }
    },
    importScripts: ["/sw.js"]
  }
```